# Obtener el mayor valor de un arraylist dentro de un objeto que está en otro arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist

Perdón por el lío que formo en el título, pero no se como ser más explícito.

Es para un ejercicio de instituto. Estoy tratando de conseguir el valor mas alto de "Venta" que tiene un trabajador dentro de un ArrayList que se encuentra dentro de un objeto (que alojo dentro de otro ArrayList). Es en Windows Forms.

Tengo por un lado (cListado.cs):

```
    private ArrayList listadoEmpleados;

    public string empleadoMayorVenta()
    {
        cEmpleado empl;
        int i, mayor, pos;
        string texto;

        for (i = 0; i < listadoEmpleados.Count; i++) 
        {
            empl = (cEmpleado)listadoEmpleados[i];
            if(empl.Mventas > mayor)
            {
                mayor = empl.Mventas;
                pos = i;
            }
        }

        empl = (cEmpleado)listadoEmpleados[pos];
        texto = empl.mostrarDatos();

        return texto;
    }
```

Y por otro (cEmpleado.cs):

```
    // DECLARACION DE MIEMBROS *******************************
    private string mNombre;
    private int mEdad;
    private ArrayList mVentas;

    //********

    public ArrayList Mventas
    {
        get{ return mVentas; }
        set{ mVentas = value; }
```

Me aparecen los siguientes errores

**El operador '>' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'object' y 'int' (CS0019) cListado.cs**

y

**No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'object' en 'int'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión) (CS0266) - cListado.cs**

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Porque no se como obtener el dato del valor mas alto del arraylist del objeto "Empleado" y compararlo. ¿Estoy planteando mal la solución?

Si necesitáis que suba los cs sin problema alguno. Tened en cuenta que estoy aprendiendo y que probablemente sea una cosa mas simple de hacer y que esté haciendo una burrada.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta línea:

```
if(empl.Mventas > mayor)
{
    mayor = empl.Mventas;
    pos = i;
}
```

`ArrayList` almacena una colección de tipo `object`, primero necesitas recorrer el `ArrayList` antes de hacer la comparación, por lo que podrías intentar:

```
for (j = 0; j < empl.Mventas.Count; j++) 
{
    if ((int)empl.Mventas[j] > mayor) 
    {
        mayor = (int)empl.Mventas[j]; pos = j; // No sé para que esto último.
    }
}
```

Esa es la razón de los dos errores que te muestra al compilar, explicandolos detalladamente:

> (CS0019): El operador `>` no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo `object` y `int`

Como el error indica, sucede al intentar evaluar un `object` con cualquier tipo que soporte un operador lógico como `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==` o `!=`, esto pasa porque `object` puede almacenar cualquier tipo de dato creado en C#, de este tipo se derivan todas las clases y estructuras de C#.

Y:

> (CS0266): No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo `object` en `int`. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)

Sucede al intentar hacer lo siguiente:

```
object a = 25; // Definir un int en un object.
int b = a;  // Asignar el object a en b
```

Que básicamente te obliga a hacer una conversión de la siguiente manera:

```
int b = (int)a;
```

Para que se elimine la advertencia.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, es justo lo que me estaba fallando. He retocado un poco el código y ahora hace justo lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

buenas  tardes.
Segun entiendo tenes un array list dentro de otro. Por lo tanto deberas usar dos bucles for, uno para el primer arraylist del cual por cada objeto recuperado deberas ussar otro for para recorrer el array que contiene el objeto recuperado del primero.
Lee la documentacion de c# y si hay metodos que devuelvan el mayor de los guardados (en java se puede hacer usando for each, o ndicando reglas con compareTo o compare)

Si en c# no ecisten tendras que ordenar el arraylist con el metodo de la burbuja, asi el mayor siempre quedara en la posicion [0] del arreglo

Answer (score 0):

1- Te recomendaría que en vez de

```
Arraylist listadoEmpleados;
```

usases

```
List<cEmpleado> listadoEmpleados;
```

Asi no tienes que estar lidiando con casting.

2- No especificas de que tipo es el ArrayList mVentas. Doy por hecho que es un arraylist de objetos ventas.
Si lo que quieres saber es cual de los empleados tiene mayor numero de ventas, se puede lograr facilmente usando LINQ:

```
cEmpleado empleadoMayorVentas = listadoEmpleados.OrderByDescending(empleado => empleado.ventas.Count).First();
```

3- Si ArrayList de mVentas es por el contrario una lista de enteros, te recomiendo usar tambien `List<int> ventas`, y lo que quieres es obtener cual es empleado con la venta mayor, puedes usar este:

```
cEmpleado empleadoMayorVentas = listaEmpleados.OrderByDescending(empleado => empleado.ventas.Max()).First();
```

4- Si sigues queriendo usar ArrayList en Ventas por sabe Dios que razón:

```
cEmpleado empleadoMayorVentas = listaEmpleados.OrderByDescending(empleado => empleado.ventas.ToArray().Max()).First();
```

Comment: Para el punto 2, `ArrayList` no es una clase genérica, pero `ArrayList<T>`, sí.

Comment: Si, pero tal como se plantea el ejercicio parece mas desconocimiento por su parte de como implementar las colecciones que el querer usar un Arraylist de objetos cualquiera. Puedo estar equivocado también.