# Obtener el mayor valor de un ArrayList que se encuentra dentro de otro ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

no se explicarme muy bien, así que directamente les dejo el enunciado de la facultad para que puedan verlo (esta es la primera clase que vemos Arrays, soy yo o es muy complicado como para recién haberlo visto?).

DISCLAIMER: Donde dice en el enunciado "se sabe el domicilio (String), yo el domicilio para que sea mas facil a la vista, ya que la palabra domicilio se mezclaba con ejercicios anteriores, la cambie por el atributo 'ID'."
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté varias cosas pero ninguna funciona bien, ya estoy harto de este ejercicio, pensé en hacer un foreach dentro de otro foreach que cuente así (desde el each de adentro hasta el each de afuera) la cantidad de propiedades por barrio y que asigne el valor mas alto al barrio correspondiente, pero me encuentro con muchos errores en el medio que no se como solucionar.

***Acá la clase Inmobiliaria.***

```
public class Inmobiliaria {
private ArrayList<Barrio> barrios;

public Inmobiliaria() {
    this.barrios = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void agregarBarrio(Barrio barrio) {
    this.barrios.add(barrio);
}

public void mostrarBarrio() {
    for (Barrio barrio : barrios) {
        System.out.println(barrio.getNombre() + ":");
        barrio.mostrarPropiedades();
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}

public ArrayList<Propiedad> mostrarPropiedadesPorTipo(TipoDePropiedad tipo) {
    ArrayList<Propiedad> propiedadesDeEsteTipo = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Barrio barrio : barrios) {
        ArrayList<Propiedad> barriosPorTipo = barrio.mostrarPropiedadesPorTipo(tipo);
        propiedadesDeEsteTipo.addAll(barriosPorTipo);
    }
    return propiedadesDeEsteTipo;
}
```

}

**Acá la clase Barrio**

```
public class Barrio {
ArrayList<Propiedad> propiedades;
private String nombre;

public Barrio(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.propiedades = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void agregarPropiedad(Propiedad propiedad) {
    this.propiedades.add(propiedad);
}

public void mostrarPropiedades() {
    for (Propiedad propiedad : propiedades) {
        System.out.println(propiedad);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Propiedad> mostrarPropiedadesPorTipo(TipoDePropiedad tipo) {
    ArrayList<Propiedad> propiedadesDeEsteTipo = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Propiedad propiedad : propiedades) {
        if (propiedad.getTipo() == tipo) {
            propiedadesDeEsteTipo.add(propiedad);
        }
    }
    return propiedadesDeEsteTipo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return propiedades + ", Nombre: " + nombre;
}
```

}

**Acá la clase Propiedad**

```
public class Propiedad {
private String ID;
private double precio;
private TipoDePropiedad tipo;

public Propiedad(String id, double precio, TipoDePropiedad tipoDePropiedad) {
    this.ID = id;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.tipo = tipoDePropiedad;
}

public TipoDePropiedad getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + ID + ", precio: " + precio + ", tipo: " + tipo;
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Con la mayor cantidad de ....????

Comment: ah justo se corto, ahi lo arreglo, pero dice el barrio con mayor cantidad de propiedades

Comment: Sé que es de C#, pero esto no te ayuda? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/67209/169744

Comment: lo vi varias veces, pero al ser codigo de un enunciado distinto me termino perdiendo y la verdad me confunde mas

Comment: La verdad me gustaría hacerlo con streams, pero no creo que aún los conozcas. Échale un vistazo a [esto](https://pastebin.com/gMBR4n0p) con dos `for`. Es bastante sencillo lo que quieres. Puede que te ayude.

Comment: impecable! funcionó!, te agradezco un monton yo la verdad que habia pensado algo super raro y que involucraba muchas cosas sin sentido,  lo que hiciste es sencillo y totalmente entendible, mil gracias!!

Comment: el codigo como lo pones no compila porque TipoPropiedad no esta presenta, aun asi podrias intentar con `return this.barrios.stream().max((barrio1, barrio2) -> Integer.compare(barrio1.propiedades.size(), barrio2.propiedades.size())).orElseThrow();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes encontrar cual es el barrio que tiene el mayor número de casas. Para ello iteras sobre los barrios y encuentras cuál es el que tiene el mayor número de propiedades.

Luego, extraes todos los barrios con el mayor número de propiedades, los guardas en una lista, y los devuelves. El método podría quedar:

```
public ArrayList<Barrio> obtenerBarrioMaxProp() {
        
        // Determina el numero de propiedades del barrio que mas propiedades tiene
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < barrios.size(); i++) {
            int propiedades = barrios.get( i ).propiedades.size();
            if (propiedades > max) {
                max = propiedades;
            }
        }
 
        // Guarda un arreglo con todos los barrios que tengan el maximo de propiedades.
        ArrayList<Barrio> barriosMaxProp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < barrios.size(); i++) {
            int propiedades = barrios.get( i ).propiedades.size();
            if (propiedades == max) {
                barriosMaxProp.add( barrios.get( i ) );
            }
        }
 
        return barriosMaxProp;
 }
```