# Método en Java hace lo que le pido, pero de manera extraña y no al pie de la letra

Tags: java

**Enunciado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que el error de este método es el `.propiedades.get(i);` ya que siempre va a estar comparando el ID del parámetro con el ID de la propiedad número 'i', entonces va a haber veces que el número de ID que yo coloque como parámetro justo coincida con el size de propiedades de ese barrio. El tema es que no sé cómo hacer para arreglarlo y que iguale el ID por parámetro con el de todas las ID la lista de propiedades del barrio en el que se encuentra el ciclo for en ese momento. ¿Alguna idea, chicos? No sé si me expresé muy bien, es que sinceramente no encuentro palabras para describir este error.

```
public void borrarPropiedad(String id) {
    Propiedad propiedadABorrar = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < barrios.size(); i++) {
        propiedadABorrar = this.barrios.get(i).propiedades.get(i);
        if (id.equals(propiedadABorrar.getID())) {
            this.barrios.get(i).propiedades.remove(propiedadABorrar);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tienes dos listas enlazadas que intentas recorrer con una única variable. Lo que estás pidiéndole es que coja el primer elemento de la primera lista, el segundo elemento de la segunda lista, el tercer elemento de la tercera lista... etc. Para recorrer dos listas completas hacen falta dos variables, no una.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/534193/obtener-el-mayor-valor-de-un-arraylist-que-se-encuentra-dentro-de-otro-arraylist

Comment: @Benito-B, y como podria implementar una segunda variable, no se me ocurre :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes recorrer en cada barrio, cada propiedad para poder encontrar la propiedad deseada. Eso significa que necesitas dos ciclos `for` anidados. Una vez que encuentres la propiedad, simplemente la eliminas con `.remove` y rompes el ciclo con un `return`. Te adjunto una posible solución. Nota que debes agregar un `getID()` en propiedad para poder tener acceso al `ID`:

```
public void borrarPropiedad(String id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < barrios.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < barrios.get( i ).propiedades.size(); j++) {
                Propiedad propiedad = barrios.get( i ).propiedades.get( j );
                if (propiedad.getID().equals(id)) {
                    barrios.get( i ).propiedades.remove( j );
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

El `getID` en la clase propiedad es simplemente:

```
public String getID() {
    return ID;
}
```

Comment: Hola jaime! mucha gracias por la ayuda, antes de ver tu respuesta, intente algo muy idento a lo que estás implementando acá, eso me da esperanza ya que significa que la logica la tengo bien, lo que me falla es el pasaje a codigo jajaja, pero bueno! es un tema nuevo para mi, recien vimos solamente 2 clases en la facultad sobre este tema. Practica y mas practica! saludos!